# How to implement for loop with else only in list comprehension?

Tags: for-loop, list-comprehension

I am trying to implement "for with else" statement in comprehension .
Usually for with if or for with if else can be implemented in the list comprehension but I am unable to implement for with for else.

I am trying below code using list comprehension. But I am unable to do so

```py
def primeNumber(self, A):
    li = []
    for i in range(2, A+1):
        for j in range(2, (int(i/2)+1)):
            if i % j == 0:
                break
        else:
            li.append(i)
    return li
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to implement the inner loop as a statement.

```py
import itertools
A = 19

li = [i for i in range(2, A+1) if len(list(itertools.takewhile(lambda j: i%j != 0, range(2, (int(i/2)+1))))) == len(range(2, (int(i/2)+1)))]    
li
```

That will result in

```
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19]
```